# Dornbracht Domani 3-way Diverter Stuck

Tags: plumbing, diverter

The Dornbracht Domani line is cancelled, so they aren’t able to provide me with technical support. Our shower/tub/wand diverter is stuck in the shower position. We can’t glean whether a replacement cartridge is available or if the diverter is otherwise serviceable. Any Dornbracht mavens out there?

[image: see photo below]

Answer (score 1):

The design of this diverter may be significantly different from the Price-Pfister that I have worked with. The wrenching flats (if there are any) seem to be well inside the wall. The hole in the granite seems an unnecessarily close fit. This could complicate removal. If you would get a diagram of the faucet, this could be a valuable guide to removing the diverter.

But based on my experience even if the diverter is stuck in one setting you should be able to remove the diverter valve. Then take it in to a plumbing supply and they would probably have a replacement or parts to repair it.

You do not need to shut off the water in the house to remove the diverter, just keep the hot and cold valves shut.

It just might need lubrication. I use a silicone grease, but ask the plumbing supply. The coarse threads that advance the valve in operation need lubrication, at least in the similar old type  Price Pfister ones that we have. The diverter in the tub shower that I use got progressively stiffer to operate. I removed it, lubed it and reinstalled it and it works OK.

I was later at a plumbing supply and asked about the diverter. The counter guy said I should bring in the diverter. He said he would need to see it to be sure of giving me the right part.

There is a special tube wrench that fits around the diverter wrenching faces.

If you get the diverter valve out, and cannot get a replacement, you could soak it in vinegar or CLR and this might free it. Then clean the hard water deposits, get new rubber parts, lube it and reinstall it.

Comment: While it's not _necessary_ to turn off the water to the _whole house_, it's a good idea to shut off supply to the tub or whole bathroom to prevent accidental bumping of the shower faucet controls while working in there, if possible. If no local shut-offs, this would be a good time to install them. At least tape the handles in place to ensure you don't accidentally pour water inside the wall while working.

Comment: Most of these old style shower valves (two separate handles/valves) were installed without cut-off valves. Thinking about my answer above it came to me that the coarse threads are entirely in the two parts of the valve body. There are no operating threads in the valve body so if you do allow progression to damage in the inner threads there would be no harm. Replacing the whole diverter gives both inner and outer operating threads.